# Django REST serializer and extra attributes from custom model fields

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

How can i pass extra attributes from my custom model field to the serializer?

For example i have this custom model field RsTestField which has an extra attribute "info" which is True or False:

```
class RsTestField(models.Field):

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "CharField"

    def __init__(self, info=False, *args, **kwargs):
        self.info = info
        super(RsTestField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_info(self):
        return self.info
```

Which is used in the following model, where i can pass the value of this custom attribute:

```
class Client(models.Model):

    test1 = RsTestField(max_length=255, info=True, default="")
    name1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
```

And the following serializer:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    test1 = ModelField(model_field=Client()._meta.get_field('test1'))

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('name1','test1')
```

I want to be able to access the test1-info attribute just like i would be able to access the name1-max_length attribute.

Is this possible?

The goal is to eventually pass this attribute in the Scheme overview which can be retrieved with the OPTIONS http request:

```
"actions": {
    "POST": {
        "name1": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": false,
            "label": "Client name 1",
            "max_length": 255
        },
        "test1": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": true,
            "read_only": false,
            "label": "Test1"
        }
    }
}
```

In "test1" there should come an extra key:

```
"info": True
```

Comment: You don't want `info` to be an actual field (column) in your DB for `RsTestField`?

Comment: No, i want to add several arguments that describe the scheme-fields so the frontend can use them to build the GUI. e.g:  'info' would mark a read-only field or information field (i know, there is a read only arg already), and for example a serial-number that would indicate ordering in the GUI layout/dictates tab-stop. 1 on top/first, 2 below that/next tab etc. So they are not data, they describe my model-fields to the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

> I want to be able to access the test1-info attribute just like i would
>   be able to access the name1-max_length attribute.

Yes, you can access your `info` attribute by `ModelField.model_field.info`.
you can see the example below.

Question 2 for your final goal:

I think you can customize your own metadata class.

```
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelField
from pbweb.models import RsTestField


class MyMetadata(SimpleMetadata):
    def get_field_info(self, field):
        field_info = super(MyMetadata, self).get_field_info(field)
        # I will add the info field only for RsTestField-ModelField
        if isinstance(field, ModelField) and isinstance(field.model_field, RsTestField):
            # access your info attribute HERE
            field_info['info'] = field.model_field.info
        return field_info
```

and, don't forget to config your `DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS` settings

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'my.customize.MyMetadata'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I was looking at it the wrong way, i was constantly trying to access the custom attributes at the Serializer level, instead of the MetaData level. In the serializer level certain data, like certain kwargs that you pass to the model-field get's discarded, and only specific kwargs are allowed/handled   (since they are not always needed for that type of field, e.g. decimal_places for a string )

Comment: Ahh.. it only get's discarded for explicit fields like CharField, not for custom subclassed models.Field types. There they are accessible through model_field. Tnx, learned a bit more today

Comment: Is there a way to add extra attributes to models.CharField for example, instead of models.Field so that the Serializer would be able to see them? (like i  mentioned before it seems that subclassing CharFields in MyCustomField, ends up in extra attributes being deleted when they get passed to the Serializer)

Comment: @squiggy how about trying to extends the models.CharField and CharField serializer. And if you wanna use ModelSerilizer, you also have to extend it and change the `serializer_field_mapping` attribute. err...it's complicated...

Comment: @squiggy the DRF works like this: the `serializer.Field` get the attribute from `models.Field`, and **store** it in the `serializer.Field`, these attribute is different by different serializer.FIeld, and the OPTIONS method i.e. `metadata`, which get attributes from `serializer.Field` directly [code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/metadata.py#L110) .

Comment: Ok i sublassed the models.CharField and made an RsCharField and added the extra field. I subclassed the serializers.CharField which takes extra kwargs, and made an mapping in a subclass for the serializers.ModelSerializer, which picks up my new RsCharField correctly.  The only thing now which i can't seem to find is how the serializer.CharField gets his arguments form the models.CharField....

Comment: @squiggy sorry for late response, [serializer.CharField \_\_init\_\_](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L565), you can access it from **kwargs['model_field'].info**.   flow: ModelSerizlier -> [build_standard_field](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L986) -> [get_field_kwargs](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py#L74).

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it, for everyone trying the same, adding extra kwargs to django-models, passing them to the rest_framework serializer, and delivering them to the Metadata scheme to get them in the OPTIONS method in a API request:

In this example i add a kwarg 'serial' to a CharField. First extend django.db.models.CharField and use it in a model:

*models.py*

```
class RsCharField(models.CharField, metaclass=models.SubfieldBase):

    def __init__(self, serial=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.serial = serial


class MyModel(models.Model):

    fied_name1 = RsCharField(max_length=100, serial=123456, default="")
```

Then create a new serializer for your new field type, eg: RsCharField below, and extend the ModelSerializer to create a mapping from the Django-model-RsCharField, to the serializer-RsCharField.

Extend the build_standard_field method of the ModelSerializer to add the extra kwargs from the django-model-RsCharField to the serializers-RsCharField

*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class RsCharField(serializers.CharField):

    def __init__(self, serial=None, **kwargs):
        self.serial = serial
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class RsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    serializer_field_mapping = serializers.ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping
    serializer_field_mapping[myapp.models.RsCharField] = RsCharField

    def build_standard_field(self, field_name, model_field):
        field_class, kwargs =  super().build_standard_field(field_name, model_field)

        if isinstance(model_field, kernel.fields.RsCharField):
            kwargs['serial'] = model_field.serial

        return field_class, kwargs
```

Finally extend SimpleMetadata to pass the new kwargs to the OPTIONS method of your api, and show it in the scheme:

```
class RsMetaData(SimpleMetadata):

    def get_field_info(self, field):

        field_info = super(RsMetaData, self).get_field_info(field)
        if(isinstance(field, RsCharField)):
            field_info['serial'] = field.serial

        return field_info
```

And adjust settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'my.customize.RsMetaData'
}
```

Probably not neat yet, but this is the idea. Tnx soooooot!

Comment: If you want to do the same for related fields, like PrimaryKeyRelatedField in the ModelsSerializer, then create a mapping at serializers.ModelSerializer.seriliazer_related_field and override the build_relational_field() method of the ModelSerializer

Comment: I suppose these two lines `serializer_field_mapping = serializers.ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping; serializer_field_mapping[myapp.models.RsCharField] = RsCharField` will also modify the dictionary `serializer_field_mapping` in the `serializers.ModelSerializer` class which is not desired side effect. Probably it is better to do a copy in the first of these lines.